# Context cannot be converted to RecognitionListener

Tags: java, android, cordova, speech-recognition

I'm implementing voice recognition plugin in Cordova.
For this I'm getting the error

```
incompatible types: Context cannot be converted to RecognitionListener
```

while building the cordova plugin.
This error came from the following code

```
context = this.cordova.getActivity();
SpeechRecognizer speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(context);
speech.setRecognitionListener(context); // Getting error here
```

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Activity needs to `implements RecognitionListener` and you must cast your generic Context object to be that interface.

```
context =  this.cordova.getActivity();
SpeechRecognizer speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(context);
speech.setRecognitionListener(( RecognitionListener) context);
```

Or you can pass an anonymous class

```
context =  this.cordova.getActivity();
SpeechRecognizer speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(context);
speech.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {});
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution